# Python - Iterate over all classes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, loops

How can I iterate over a list of all classes loaded in memory? 
I'm thinking of doing it for a backup, looking for all classes inheriting from db.Model (Google App Engine).

Thanks,
Neal Walters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In "normal" Python, you can reach all objects via the `gc.getobjects()` function of the `gc` standard library module; it's then very easy to loop on them, checking which one are classes (rather than instances or anything else -- I do believe you mean *instances* of classes, but you can very easily get the classes themselves too if that's really what you want), etc.

Unfortunately, the `gc` module in App Engine does NOT implement `getobjects` -- which makes it extremely difficult to reach ALL classes. For example, a class created by calling:

```
def makeaclass():
  class sic(object): pass
  return sic
```

and hidden into a list somewhere, IS going to be very difficult to reach.

But fortunately, since you say in your question's text that you only care about subclasses of `db.Model`, that's even easier than `gc` would allow:

```
for amodel in db.Model.__subclasses__():
   ...
```

Just make sure you explicitly ignore such classes you don't care about, such as `Expando`;-).

Note that this DOES give you only and exactly the CLASSES, **not** the instances -- there is no similarly easy shortcut if *those* are what you're really after!

Answer (score 2):

Classes are defined in modules.  Modules are created by an `import` statement.

Modules are simply dictionaries.  If you want, you can use the `dir(x)` function on a module named `x`

Or you can use `x.__dict__` on a module named `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on S.Lott's response: 
This works if I omit the "if issubclass" except then I get classes I don't want.

```
  import dbModels 
  self.response.out.write("<br/><br/>Class Names:</br/>")
  for item in dbModels.__dict__:
      if issubclass(item, db.Model):
         self.response.out.write("<br/>" + item)
```

The above gives error:

> TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be
>   a class

So it wants a classname as a parm, not an object name apparently.

Based on Alex's answer, this worked great:

```
  self.response.out.write("<br/><br/>Class Names Inheriting from db.Model:</br/>")
  for item in db.Model.__subclasses__():
       self.response.out.write("<br/>" + item.__name__)
```

Thanks to both!

Neal